# How to write a formula for this infinite sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series

My first term at $n=1$ is $$\sqrt 2 $$ 2nd term at $n=2$ is $$\sqrt {\sqrt 2+2} $$ So I am adding 2 to the previous term then taking the square root of the entire equation.
At $n=3$ I have $$\sqrt {\sqrt {\sqrt {2}+2}+2}$$ And so on.
I want to sum all terms to infinite.

Comment: The terms actually approaches to $2$. It can be solved by the equation $x^2-2=x$ . So the sum would not converge since you are adding more and more

Comment: $x_1 = \sqrt{2}$, $x_{n+1} = \sqrt{x_n + 2}$

Comment: Interestingly, each term in your sequence has the closed form $2\cos \frac{\pi}{2^n}$

Comment: @zz20s cool! How to prove that?

Comment: @ant You may want to do a google search for "Viete's formula for pi."

Answer (score 4):

So you have $a_1 = \sqrt 2$, $a_n = \sqrt{a_{n-1}  + 2}$

Now suppose that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = S$ exists, then it must hold

$$S = \sqrt{S + 2}$$ which has as positive solution $S = 2$

Now, you want to find $$\sum_{n  =1}^\infty a_n$$

A necessary condition for the sum to converge is that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$$ So either the limit does not exists (and the sum does not converge) or the limit exists and for what we showed before it must be $2 \neq 0$; hence your sum does not converge